# Discord.js: (node:147) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js, bots

So recently for some unknown reason, I started seeing regular errors in the console. Like this:

```
(node:147) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded
    at createError (/home/runner/ricebot/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/home/runner/ricebot/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:280:16)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at RedirectableRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/ricebot/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:166:12)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

It also sometimes make my bot's latency go to 30000 ms.

I only have Axios parts in my fun commands and here is one of them (however it still works properly, just logs the error):

```js
const url = 'https://no-api-key.com/api/v2/animals/cat';

        let image;
        let fact;
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(url);
            console.log(data);
            image = data.image;
            fact = data.fact;
        } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
            return message.channel.send('An error occured, please try again!');
        }
```

This didn't use to be a thing.

Comment: It seems like axios cant get your url

Comment: @ChristophBlüm it gets it, the axios part works

Comment: @8less please, can you provide a bit more of code, since you are using await you are in a function and also what doesn't ```console.log(data);``` display ? <- if as you said the axios part is working

Comment: @Saren it logs everything it should:
{
  fact: 'Disneyland Park “employs” nearly 200 cats.',
  image: 'https://no-api-key.com/image/cat/95147.png'
}

Comment: Maybe try to destructure it after? `const a = await axios.get(url); const { data } = a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your axios call doesn't have a catch it is normal to get this error or warning.

It is important to manage axios requests to prevent these kind of issues. Also, I assume, the sample you show is missing some data because you won't need to define result variables outside of the catch state, so I assume you have a loop or something that can cause this as well.

If you are making calls to same endpoint in a loop or with Promise.all, sometimes you need to limit concurrent requests. If it is not the case please ignore this part.

First of all, make sure to set your `axios.default.timeout` value correctly to define when to cancel the request if there was is response.

Define a response status check your with your requirements.

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }
  const error: any = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}
```

Define a parse code to make sure you always have same structure.

```
function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.data;
}
```

Define a catch functionality to check errors and decide whether to throw errors or just log them.

```
function catchError(e){
  console.error(e);
  // TODO send a message
  return null;
}
```

Let's use them in a single call with .catch.

```
const myResult = await axios.get(url)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(catchError);
console.log(myResult);
```

Comment: hey, that's a good answer, but i dont have ANY part of axios in my code since i commented it out and it still sends these errors

Comment: @8less Please update your code in here as well. How could you get this error without having axios ? ` at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/home/runner/ricebot/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:280:16)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)`

Comment: axios itself is installed, but not required anywhere and used

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken, you can't access properties from a promise directly, as declaring a variable from a property is synchronous while your `url()` method is asynchronous.
The data type of `axios.get(url)` is `Promise` when the response is not returned so it doesn't have a `data` property which you are accessing early on. Therefore you have to wait for the response. As when the response is returned the data type of that method changes to what it is intended to be. That's when you can access the `data` property
So I think your code should be like the following:

```js
const url = 'https://no-api-key.com/api/v2/animals/cat';
let image;
let fact;
try {
    const axiosUrl = await axios.get(url);
    const data = axiosUrl.data;
    console.log(data);
    image = data.image;
    fact = data.fact;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return message.channel.send('An error occured, please try again!');
}
```

Assuming that this block of code is in an async context, it should work fine.
I hope this answer was of use for you.